# ¿Como cambiarle la clase a un icono de font awesome?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

tengo un problema lo que pasa es que cuando pongo font awesome en mi footer tiene clases por defecto y al momento de poner los mismos iconos en mi menu modal 
me aparece con las mismas ediciones que las que tengo en mi footer y nos se abra alguna manera de cambiarle la clase de ese font awesome si que afecte su funcionamiento para que pueda tener los mismo iconos del fotter pero en mi menu modal pero con diferentes aspectos

este es mi footer
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es mi menu modal con las mismos font awesome

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

yo quiero que no tengan los mismos estilos pero no se puede porque tienen clases iguales

Comment: lo mejor para poderte ayudar es que coloques el código minimo funcional para poder comprender que es lo que te esta pasando y cual es el resultado que esperas obtener

Comment: me puedes ayudar mi codigo html y css3 cuando lo pego solo reconoce un pesado del código y no lo demás tiene comentarios  y mas código pero eso lo toma como texto normal

Comment: pégalo en orden en tu pregunta y usa el ícono **{}** para darle formato una vez lo selecciones, si aún asi no pudieras yo ayudo dándole formato

Comment: lo puedo subir a mega y lo puedes poner en mi pregunta

Comment: @MarcoOyolaYacolca Tal vez te sirva [¿Qué es Stack Snippet?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3292/65)

Comment: me dice que esta limitado a 30000 caracteres  y dice que tengo como 38667 lo que pasa es que estoy poniendo mi css y mi html y mi css ahi alguna manera de ponerlos por separado en mi misma pregunta ??

Comment: Podrias mudar tu código a [Code Pen][https://codepen.io/#] y luego mandar el link para verificarlo.

Comment: que raro no puedo copiar y pegar mi codigo donde dice html

Comment: me lee mi codigo correctamente pero como la gran mayoria son imagenes no aparecen y mi menu modal no aparece al darle click en el botón de manu

Comment: alguien que me resuelva esa duda por favor no hace falta que les muestre mi codigo quiero saber si se puede hacer eso de cambiarle la clase al icono de font awesome sin que afecte su funcionamiento

Comment: @MarcoOyolaYacolca por favor es **muy importante que leas** [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Solo tienes que sobreescribir los estilos poniendo por ejemplo: `.menu-modal .fa-facebook{}`y ahí añades lo que necesites

Answer (score 0):

Para eso, si mal no entiendo, debes usar el selector padre que contiene los iconos para especificar cada caso:

```
.menu-modal .redes .fab {
  /* estilos para los iconos del modal */
} 

.pie-de-pagina .redes-sociales .fab {
  /* estilos para los iconos del footer */
}
```

Te recomiendo tambien que uses algun preprocesador, como sass, para hacerte la vida más fácil (mucho) y además poder cargar unicamente los íconos que necesitas